# How to make xbl image not inherit list-style-image

Tags: firefox-addon, xbl

I have this xbl binding:

```
  <binding id="toolbarbutton" display="xul:button" role="xul:toolbarbutton"
           extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/button.xml#button-base">
    <resources>
      <stylesheet src="chrome://global/skin/toolbarbutton.css"/>
    </resources>

    <content>
      <children includes="observes|template|menupopup|panel|tooltip"/>
      <xul:stack>
        <xul:image class="toolbarbutton-icon" xbl:inherits="validate,src=image,label"/>
        <xul:image class="profilist-badge" xbl:inherits="validate,src=badge,label"/>
      </xul:stack>
```

However when `list-style-image` is set on the `toolbarbutton` (which is the parent of the `stack` these `image`s are in, the `image.profilist-badge` element is taking this `list-style-image` when i want it to be blank :( my current workaround is to set the `badge` property of the `toolbarbutton` to an image that doesnt exist.

this is low priority question. just asking so i can document this some day on mdn. in my addon i default the list-image to `chrome://mozapps/skin/places/defaultFavicon.png` by setting the class of the badge anon node:

```
.PanelUI-profilist .profilist-badge {
    list-style-image: url(chrome://mozapps/skin/places/defaultFavicon.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, XUL/XBL is a bit special when it comes to `list-style-image` and inheritance.

Only way I know is adding `list-style-image: none` to avoid a sub-tree `xul:image` taking over an `list-style-image` value of a parent element.